# Make array hold 10 latest entries

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a array to hold the 10 latest values, so far it cant get it to work.

```
var messages = new Array(10);

function addmessage(message) {
    messages.unshift(message);
    messages.length = 10;
}
```

But when i try to show the array i cant get it to show the messages in order...

And i display the array with

```
$.each(messages, function(key, value) {
    if(value != null) {
        $("#messages").append(value + "<br>");
    }
});
```

Comment: Accessing a missing member will return a value of `undefined`, so your test is depdending on type conversion. Consider `if (key in this)`.

Answer (score 6):

```
var messages = []; //use an array literal instead.

function addmessage(message) {  

    //unshift loads the new value into the beginning
    messages.unshift(message);

    //if you want to place it in the end, you can use push()
    //messages.push(message);

    //if you really want it to remain 10,  pop off the last
    if(messages.length > 10){
        messages.pop();
        //and if push()
        //messages.shift()
    }              
}

//loop through and append, "latest" first
$.each(messages, function(key, value) {

    if(value != null) {
        $("#messages").append(value + "<br>");
    }

});
```

if you then load messages realtime/dynamically with latest first, [you can use `.prepend()`](http://jsfiddle.net/qYsXn/)

Comment: Yep, and also `if ( messages.length > 10 ) messages.pop()`

Comment: nice tip, never thought about starting from 0 :D

Comment: Latest should be last so .prepend() is not needed.

Comment: what order do  you really want?

Comment: well, its for a chat so it keeps the 10 last messages and then it should show them in the order they came in so i guess i could use `push()` instead of `unshift()` and then use `shift()` instead of `pop()`

Comment: if the latest is the last in the array, then yes, you can use `push()` and `shift()` instead.

Comment: `["006", "011", "010", "003", "009", "008", "007", "005", "001", "004", "002"]` this is the order that i get...

Answer (score 1):

In it's simplest form, you can have:

```
messages.push(message);
messages.length > 9 && messages.shift();
```

That will add new messages on the end and remove one from the front once the length gets to 10.

Answer (score 0):

[Try this solution](http://fiddle.jshell.net/erDS3/2/), maybe you want you items in the reverse order?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of order do you expect ? You put the entries in the beginning of the array, so the order is inversed.

For example:

```
addmessage('test'); addmessage('test2'); addmessage('test4');
addmessage('test6'); addmessage('test23'); addmessage('test34');
addmessage('test32'); addmessage('test3'); addmessage('test45');
addmessage('test7'); addmessage('test8');
```

Results in an array like this:

```
["test8", "test7", "test45", "test3", "test32", "test34", "test23", "test6", "test4", "test2"]
```

if you want to have it the other way around you function should look like this:

```
function addmessage(message){
  messages.push(message);
  messages.shift();
}
```

Which results in the inverse:

```
["test2", "test4", "test6", "test23", "test34", "test32", "test3", "test45", "test7", "test8"]
```

Comment: well, they didnt come in order at all.